# testing if value is numeric is not working when submitting a form

Tags: jquery, validation, submit, numeric

i'm having a simple code to check if the value is numeric before submitting the form but the form submits even it's not a numeric value

```
<form action="asdasd" method="POST" id="my_form" >
<input type="text" name="userphone" id="userphone" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="register" />
</form>
```

js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#userphone').blur(function () {
var phone = $("#userphone").val();
var phonelen = phone.length;

if (!$.isNumeric(phone) || phonelen<6) {
    $("#userphone").css("background-color", "#ff9f9f");
    return false;
} else {
    $("#userphone").css("background-color", "#fff");
    return true;
}
})
});

function check_user_phone(){ 
var phone = $("#userphone").val();
var phonelen = phone.length;

if (!$.isNumeric(phone) || phonelen<6) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
} 

$("#my_form").submit(function(){
 if (!check_user_phone()) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
})
```

but the form is still submitting data even if phone value is not numeric

Comment: Looks to me like you want to attach event handlers to the form being submitted, at present you're just attaching a handler to the phone number input losing focus.

Comment: your code is perfectly working http://jsfiddle.net/9Lpsw/1/

Comment: @jq beginner onsubmit ,onblur is not supported in js fiddle

Comment: @jq beginner your code working fine.

Comment: code updated please review

Comment: thanks @rajesh kakawat for your help i got it working.

Comment: thanks @Lakshmana Kumar for your help i got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try changing the JSFiddle option from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`

**JSFiddle:-**http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/wfpbV/5/

**JS**

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("#reg").submit(function(e){
        if(!check_phone() ){  
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i guess the form is submitting even if data is not numeric. The page loads

Comment: @jqbeginner - No it's not, check it in the browser console(chrome/FF).